# Native Login Screen for Website

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, nsurlconnection

I'm having trouble logging into a website from my app using HTTP POST. I've used POST to submit a Google form and I'm guessing this would be done in essentially the same way. The problem I'm having with the login is that it always comes back as successful no matter what credentials are entered. How can I log into this site from my app and have it open a web view with the site for that user?

Here is what I have now:

```
- (IBAction)signIn
{
    if (emailAddress.text.length == 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *emailAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"You must enter the email address associated with your account" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [emailAlert show];
    }
    else if (password.text.length == 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *passwordAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"You must enter your password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [passwordAlert show];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *email = emailAddress.text;
        NSString *passwordString = password.text;

        NSString *encodedEmail = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)email,NULL,(CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));
        NSString *encodedPassword = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)passwordString,NULL,(CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));

        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"https://my.kyfb.com/"];
        NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *paramDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@", encodedEmail, encodedPassword];

        NSData *paramData = [paramDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:paramData];

        NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
        [urlConnection start];
    }
}

- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSArray *trustedHosts = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"https://my.kyfb.com/", nil];

    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
        if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    UIAlertView *confirmSubmission = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Succeeded!" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [confirmSubmission show];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"CONNECTION ERROR: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    UIAlertView *submitFailed = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed!" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [submitFailed show];
}
```

Response:

```
RESPONSE: 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head> 
    <title>my.KYFB</title>
    <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />
    <meta name="GOOGLEBOT" content="NOARCHIVE" />
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
    <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
    <meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui.portal.ext.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login-reg.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/nodealert.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.portal.ext.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/liveval.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <script type="text/javascript">var checkmark=String.fromCharCode(10003);</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="padding:6px;">
        <h3>No Turing Test</h3>
        <p>You appear to have skipped our turing test or the result has expired. Please try again.</p>
        <noscript> 
            <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="margin:4px; padding:6px;">
            <p>Your browser does not support javascript or you have it disabled. Javascript is required for this site.</p>
            <p>You will not be able to pass our turing test without javascript.</p>
            </div>
        </noscript>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">

    <div>
        <p>Kentucky Farm Bureau &bull; 1-800-206-6887<br />
        9201 Bunsen Parkway &bull; Louisville &bull; KY &bull; 40220-3792<br />
        <small>&copy; Copyright 2012 Kentucky Farm Bureau. All rights reserved. <a href="https://www.kyfb.com/privacy-policy/" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a></small></p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats the response code / response data?

Comment: bro I can guide you with ios part only.

Comment: ok so on what basis you are validating the user?

Comment: ok, so there will be some response as well, like if email and password are same return true else false etc